# Editor.js lifecycle hooks

Tags: javascript, hook, lifecycle, editorjs

How do I implement the lifecyle hooks for blocks?

https://editorjs.io/tools-api#lifecycle-hooks

I have this:

```
let config = { 
    /** 
     * Id of Element that should contain the Editor 
     */ 
    holder : 'alinea-5', 
    
    /** 
     * Available Tools list. 
     * Pass Tool's class or Settings object for each Tool you want to use 
     */ 
    tools: {
        header  : Header,
        list        : List
    }
};

const elEditorData = document.querySelector('.js-editor-data');

if (elEditorData.value) {
    config.data         = {};
    config.data.blocks  = JSON.parse(elEditorData.value);
}

new EditorJS(config);
```

[image]

As you can see there is some editor.js stuff out there.

I need to clean up my html when removing a block.
Now I have to do something with lifecycle hook "removed", but how?
When deleting the block via the toolbar I want to clean up the whole html block:

```
document.querySelector('.alinea-5').remove();
```

Is this interfering with what the documentation is saying about the delete event?

> removed : Called after Block contents is removed from the page **but before Block
> instance deleted**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block Lifecycle Hooks are available inside blocks:

```js
class MyBlockTool {
   /**
   * Called after Block content is added to the page
   */
  rendered() {}

  /**
   * Called each time Block content is updated
   */
  updated() {}

  /**
   * Called after Block content is removed from the page but before Block instance deleted
   */
  removed() {}

  /**
   * Called after Block is moved by move tunes or through the API
   * 
   * @param {MoveEvent} event 
   */
  moved(event) {}
}
```